# How many concurrent session is allowed in Colab Pro +

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have subscribed the Colab Pro +. However, I found I can still open 1 session only. Therefore, it seems there is no difference between Colab Pro. Does it design to be like this? Is it possible to use multiple sessions in Colab Pro +?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: @dbonneville Seem always allows only one session of P100. No V100 provided anymore. I do not suggest to subscribe it.

Comment: thanks @maple. i ended up getting a second colab pro on a secondary google account! 20 bucks for 2 solid GPUs feels reasonable and is productive. i could almost imagine a 3rd to keep the ideas flowing but it's more rare that i'd have 3 ideas going at the same time. in that case i could use a free one, slow, to let something cook in the background and check on it without worrying about speed.